# DRF Serailze Parent-Child Relation models

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have Parent-Children Relation Table in Model which is as follows:

**models.py**

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(to='ProductCategory', blank=True, null=True, related_name="sub_cats", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, db_column='description')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

[Data in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCuRu.png)

Using this data I want to make a tree in react component where a user see how many types of categories a product has.

**right now getting this**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parent": null,
    "name": "Electronics",
    "desc": "All kinds of electronics items comes in this category",
    "sub_cats": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "parent": 1,
        "name": "Mobiles",
        "desc": "Category for Smartphones, Features-Phone, etc.",
        "sub_cats": [3]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "parent": 1,
    "name": "Mobiles",
    "desc": "Category for Smartphones, Features-Phone, etc.",
    "sub_cats": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "parent": 2,
        "name": "X-Mobile",
        "desc": "All Smartphones of X-Mobile",
        "sub_cats": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "parent": 2,
    "name": "X-Mobile",
    "desc": "All Smartphones of X-Mobile",
    "sub_cats": []
  }
]
```

or any other idea for making tree

Comment: This can easily get problematic where a simple category can result in an enormous amount of data. Usually, working with *unlimited* recursion is not a good idea.

Comment: Yaa, but if we do something like if there is no sub_cats available than stop,(i guess), or any other idea

Comment: yes, but the point is that for a single category id, it can result in an enormous JSON blob that might run the server unresponsive, or the browser due to memory problems. Usually it fetches data for one, or perhaps two levels, and then makes extra queries if the user opens one of these items. Usually populating the entire tree of some sort of "tree view" is not a good idea, especially since users usually never browse the entire tree, so it wastes bandwidth and memory.

Comment: I get your point. Thanks. and one more thing is that Is there any other way to see that categories rather than tree.